# Dell Precision Workstation T5500 Upgrade

Tags: motherboard, upgrade

I am looking to upgrade this computer, which contains the motherboard model 0CRH6C. What Xeon CPUs are supported by this board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatible or supported CPUs are nearly always determined by the socket of the mainboard.

A little googling showed me the [socket on this mainboard](https://www.google.com/search?q=mainboard%200CRH6C) is the LGA 1366, and [the CPUs supported by that socket](https://www.google.com/search?q=LGA%201366%20cpus) are:

- Intel Core i7 (9xx series)
- Intel Xeon (35xx, 36xx, 55xx, 56xx series)
- Intel Celeron P1053

Comment: For the question asker, here is a [list of CPU's with LGA 1366 socket type](http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?s=t&SocketsSupported=FCLGA1366)

Comment: Thanks - So that board will accept all of the CPUs you listed without the possibility of it refusing to boot up? The only reason I ask is because I didn't want to spend money on new CPUs and have them not work. (As I wasn't aware the board could accept anything other than Xeon.) Also, I assume that the X56xx xeon series is incompatible?

Comment: That is not a statement that can be made. CPUs developed after the BIOS was updated could require a BIOS update to support. Other random faults could also cause issues when you install an updated CPU. However, the spec docs from Dell for this model workstation note it supports the Xeon 5600 series CPUs, which are the highest/newest models in the socket list, so the odds are in your favor.

Comment: Thanks - But it should support both the E5600 and the X5600 series CPUs? Also - I was wondering if you could post a link to the doc you are referring to.

Comment: http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-Precision-T5500-SpecSheet.pdf

Comment: I see nothing to deny that possibility, all the prior caveats still applying. Still, considering the Xeon X price tags, I'd be very hesitant putting a thousand-dollar CPU inside this as an upgrade. Not that it wouldn't work, but that $1000 worth of upgrades may be better spent elsewhere, or placed in savings for a future computer. But that is my opinion.

Comment: Yep that's a good point I will have to research the prices of them to see what the best option is - thanks your answers helped a lot.